# Como funciona strcpy() en C con punteros

Tags: c

Hola tengo dudas respecto a como funciona la siguiente funcion, la saque del libro de c de  Kernighan y Ritchie. No comprendo como funciona el argumento del while porque se puedo sacar el caracter nulo. Como seria que funciona? Gracias

Este seria el argumento del while que no comprendo

```
    void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
       while (*s++ = *t++)
           ;
}
```

En el libro tambien menciona la siguiente funcion pero dice que es innecesario comparar con el caracter nulo

```
    void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
       while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
           ;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- `VAR++` es el operador de post-incremento.
- `*` es el operador de indirección.
- Todo valor `!= 0` es considerado como *verdadero*.
- El valor `0` es *falso*.
- Las cadenas se finalizan con un *byte* `0`.
- `strcpy( )` copia tanto la cadena como su *byte* delimitador `0`.

La condición dentro del `while( )` puede leerse como:

- Copia el contenido apuntado por `t` en la dirección de memoria apuntada por `s`.
- Compara el valor de la posición de memoria apuntada por `s` y sale del bucle si es `== 0`
- Incrementa los punteros `s` y `t`.

> En el libro tambien menciona la siguiente funcion pero dice que es innecesario comparar con el caracter nulo

Totalmente correcto. Esa comparación **ya se está haciendo**, puesto que se está comparado el valor **después de copiarlo**, y ya dijimos que las cadenas se finalizan con `0` y este es tratado como *false*.

Comment: El `while` usa post-incremento: primero copia, luego compara, finalmente incrementa los punteros.

Comment: Huy *carajo*. Muy cierto. Que se me va la pinza a veces. Gracias por la corrección :-)

Comment: Un punto que igual confunde es que no es habitual usar el hecho de que la operación de asignación devuelve el valor asignado. Es decir, que `i = j = k = 3;` se lee como "se asigna 3 a k, la operación devuelve 3 que se asigna a j, la operación devuelve 3 que se asigna a i".

Comment: Gracias! ya quedo resuelta mi duda